# Number of points where f(x) = sqrt(x^2) + [x]^2 , x belongs to [-2,2] is discontinuous is (where [.] represents the greatest integer function)

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

My answer is 5 points : -2,-1,0,1,2. However, the answer given is 4 points : -1,0,1,2.

The way I've done it is :

f(x) ultimately boils down to : |x| + [x]^2. |x| is continuous at all points and [x] is discontinuous at integers. So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[  x ] $ represents the Greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

So for numbers in the interval $[-2,-1)$,  $[x] = -2 \Rightarrow [x]^2 = 4$.

So it is continuous at $-2$ in the right-hand side.

The function is defined over the interval $[-2,2]$, so we consider the continuity in the right-hand side of $2$.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the last line. What I did was take limits of -2+ and -2- for which [x] is discontinuous at x=-2.

Comment: No, in this case we have to consider the continuity by taking values of $f(-2)$ and $f(-2^+)$. Because we don't know the definition of the function for $x< -2$

Comment: So why don't we consider only 2-? Because if we consider only 2-, then shouldn't the function be continuous at x=2 as well?

Comment: @ArjunMukhopadhyay Nope! for values in the interval $[1,2)$ , $[x] = 1$ and not $2$, please check the definition of the GIF

Comment: Oh right! We basically count 2 and 2- ! [x] yields two different values for the two numbers.